# Rails facebook invitation and keep track

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, associations, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I would like to create a fb invitation system, where a signed up user can invite his/her friends on facebook for my app. This part is fine i have some thoughts how to do it.

But, i would like to give points to user who send the invitations, if the invited friends accepts the requests ( signs up for app).

I could not figured it out how i can associate the invited friends and keep track if they login and give points to person who invited them.

I have a user model where i will add uid, name and username for fb login but how to associate is a questionmark.

Thank you

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests#trackingrequests

Comment: @CBroe the link is not working

Comment: Works fine for me …?